# How to retrieve month number for a fiscal month using MDX in SSAS?

Tags: reporting-services, sql-server-2012, ssas, mdx

I want to calculate the `average Delivered YTD qty` over the period of months provided by the user. How do I get the fiscal month number . I tried introducing a new attribute Fiscal month number but it is returning the value "All Periods" thus becoming useless in my calculations. Any idea how do I get the month numbers. I would like to avoid hard-coding of data :)

```
WITH 
  MEMBER [Selected Fiscal Year] AS 
    [Date].[Fiscal Year].CurrentMember.Properties("MEMBER_KEY") 
  MEMBER [Selected Fiscal Month] AS 
    [Date].[Fiscal Month].CurrentMember.Properties("MEMBER_Value") 
  MEMBER [FM NUMBER] AS 
    [Date].[Fiscal Month Number].CurrentMember.Properties("MEMBER_Value") 
SELECT 
  {
    [Measures].[Delivered Qty]
   ,[Measures].[Delivered YTD QTY]
   ,Measures.[Selected Fiscal Month]
   ,Measures.[FM NUMBER]
  } ON COLUMNS
 ,{
      [Date].[Fiscal Month].&[Selected Fiscal Year]&[1]
    : 
      [Date].[Fiscal Month].&[2015]&[12]
  } ON ROWS
FROM [My Warehouse]
WHERE 
  [Date].[Fiscal Year].&[2015];
```

Comment: when you say month number I assume you mean that for say Jan this would be 1, Feb =2 etc ?

Comment: it is possible to deconstruct the `MEMBER_KEY` into its constituent parts. What format is your member_key ? YYYYMMDD so today it is 20150318 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get most of what you need from the `MEMBER_KEY` attribute:

```
WITH 
  MEMBER [Measures].[k] AS 
    [Date].[Calendar].CurrentMember.Member_Key 
  MEMBER [Measures].[yearNum] AS 
    Fix([Measures].[k] / 10000) 
  MEMBER [Measures].[monthNum] AS 
    Fix(([Measures].[k] - Fix([Measures].[k] / 10000) * 10000) / 100) 
  MEMBER [Measures].[dayNum] AS 
    Fix([Measures].[k] - Fix([Measures].[k] / 100) * 100) 
  MEMBER [Measures].[backTogetherAsDate!!] AS 
    Dateserial
    (
      [Measures].[yearNum]
     ,[Measures].[monthNum]
     ,[Measures].[dayNum]
    ) 
   ,format_string = 'dd mmm yyyy' 
SELECT 
  {
    [Measures].[k]
   ,[Measures].[yearNum]
   ,[Measures].[monthNum]
   ,[Measures].[dayNum]
   ,[Measures].[backTogetherAsDate!!]
  } ON 0
 ,Tail([Date].[Calendar].[Date]) ON 1
FROM [Adventure Works];
```

Results in this:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply .. It helps a lot.. But is there any way I can get the fiscal month. I may try a switch case where I can check if the month number is greater than 6 then reduce 6 else add 6. But is there any better method to achieve that ? :)